# Type III SS, anova - comparison to residuals

Tags: r, residuals, sums-of-squares

Apologies if this topic seems to have been beaten to death, but I couldn't find an exact duplicate. Take this data in R:

```
test <- data.frame(Y = c(41, 43, 50, 51, 43, 53, 54, 46, 45, 55, 56, 60, 58, 62, 62,
56, 47, 45, 46, 49, 58, 54, 49, 61, 52, 62, 59, 55, 68, 63, 43, 56, 48, 46, 47, 59,
46, 58, 54, 55, 69, 63, 56, 62, 67),
A = factor(rep(1:3,each=15),labels=c("A1", "A2", "A3")),
B = factor(rep(rep(1:3,3), c(3,5,7,5,6,4,5,4,6)), labels=c("B1", "B2", "B3")) )
```

Now if I use `drop1` to get a Type III, SPSS/SAS style anova result, I get:

```
z <- lm(Y ~ A + B, data=test, contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
drop1(z, .~., test = "F")

#Single term deletions
#       Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC F value   Pr(>F)    
#A       2    238.48 1258.1 155.88  4.6779  0.01494 *    # A after B 
#B       2   1253.19 2272.8 182.50 24.5817 1.09e-07 ***  # B after A
```

If I fit a model predicting the residuals left over after fitting `B`, by `A`, I figured I would get the same result as above, but it is marginally different.

```
anova(lm(resid(lm(Y ~ B)) ~ A, data=test))

#          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
#A          2  232.33 116.164  4.7563 0.01374 *
#Residuals 42 1025.77  24.423
```

I gather I'm missing something elementary, but why is this?

Comment: You forgot the fact that the predictors correlate with each other. The pure (type III) effect of A is not the effect of A on the residuals left after `Y~B` but the effect, on these residuals, of _that portion_ of A which is independent of B. To make sure and for simplicity, take two continuous predictors X1 and X2 (instead of factors A and B). Regress `Y~X1+X2`, note SS of X1. Regress `Y~X2` and get residuals RYX2. Regress `X1~X2` and get residuals RX1X2. Regress `RYX2~RX1X2`.

Comment: @ttnphns - Right you are - could you add this as an answer? I think it covers my misunderstanding well.